# Which tool has this database file been exported from?

Tags: database, filemaker, file-format

I have got a text file which I know has been created by a database application which I thought was Filemaker but I can't find any export format in Filemaker which looks like this :

[image: screenshot]

- records end with a line containing 60 times the character "*"
- each line contains field_name: value

Any idea which tool should have been used to produce this file?

Comment: In general, you should not show images for a plain-text output; you could easily have copied and pasted from the terminal to the question.  When doing so, format the data in the text box as you want it to look, ignoring the preview.  Then select it and press the **`{}`** button above the text box to indent it as code.  Now look at the preview to ensure it is as you want it.

Comment: I don't know of a tool that specifically generates that format, but it looks like the sort of thing that could easily be coded up by a 'report generator' tool for any given table.

Comment: Not quite clear what the purpose of your question is. Questions about finding a tool are off topic for SO. If you're asking if such report *can* be produced from FileMaker, the answer is yes.

Comment: @michael.hor257k my question is about finding what is the format of this file I have been given so that I can find some python libraries to process them easily. Filemaker was my first guess for the origin of the file but I was thinking there was a defined export format. From your answer I understand it might be a custom export from FM and that I will need to write my own parser.

Comment: I am not aware of an established format that looks like that (esp. with the blank lines that appear to be separating between logical groups of fields). Anyway, parsing this should be fairly trivial in any tool (post a question about that, if you can't make it work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to gather more information regarding this file, and my guess was wrong, it was not originating from filemaker but rather from a museum management software called [micromusée](http://www.mobydoc.fr/produits/micromusee-details.htm), leaving this information there in case someone finds this thread in the future.

Comment: Nice find! You should edit your question and replace the image with plain text, that would make it easier to search for.